# Changing Chrome account using Extension API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to change active Chrome user Google account or open new window with another Chrome user account using some extension API or other Chrome API?

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the [API index for extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index), you'll see that nothing matches what you seek.

Probably closest is [`chrome.identity` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity), but while it allows you to query / listen to changes, you can't initiate a change yourself.

As for having windows with separate user accounts, I'm not sure Chrome even can do that (outside Incognito session).

Can't quickly find any feature requests to that effect on crbug.com.